# How to do OOP with Pascal?

Tags: pascal, delphi

I am learning OOP with the pascal programming language.After googling the Internet, I found the [OOP -- The GNU Pascal Manaul](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc-es/OOP.html).

What does this function declaration mean?

`function Baz (b, a, z: Char) = s: Str100;  { not virtual }`

I have never seen `= xx` before, and it seems that the pascal syntax does not have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be some nonstandard extension. The implementation of the function in question is:

```
function FooParent.Baz (b, a, z: Char) = s: Str100;
begin
  WriteStr (s, 'FooParent.Baz (', b, ', ', a, ', ', z, ')')
end;
```

Normally in Pascal, the name of the function is used as the function return variable, so the above function would be written like this:

```
function FooParent.Baz (b, a, z: Char): Str100;
begin
  WriteStr (Baz, 'FooParent.Baz (', b, ', ', a, ', ', z, ')')
end;
```

It appears that the `= s` syntax indicates that the return value of the function is stored in the variable `s` inside the function body. I'm not sure why that would need to be exposed in the object interface, though.

Comment: It has to be in the interface because it's in the implementation. One of the "new features" of GPC is that "repeated function headings (in forward declarations and interfaces) are checked stricter: if one has a result variable, so must the other (according to the OOE draft)." http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc-es/News.html#News

Comment: All Object Pascal is a non-standard extension. The object Pascal draft was never ratified.

Answer (score -11):

I can't answer your question but I suggest to learn OOP with a language like [Python](http://docs.python.org/) or [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/). Pascal isn't really something on which you'll be able to build a career. I'd rather suggest that as a third or fourth language to give you some ideas how other languages work but not as your first/main language.

Both offer an interactive console (for Python, I suggest [iPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/)) where you can do small experiments.

Note: Some people attack me on the grounds that I don't know much about Pascal. I'm not sure where you get that idea. I have over 200K points on SO, I know 30 programming languages (know == written large amounts of code in it), I've written code in Pascal at the beginning of my career.

I understand it hurts when your beloved programming language doesn't get the recognition you feel it deserves. A no brainer: You made the decision to use that language, so it must be the best one - otherwise your decision would be wrong.

But when I compare code written in all the languages that I know, Pascal/Delphi/Modula/Oberon are among those which I don't recommend for various reasons. Delphi got some traction because of Borland but that's over. I've seen the code which good Delphi programmers wrote and my first thought was: Maintenance cost.

Comment: -1 "I can't answer your question." Then don't post an answer. Post a comment.

Comment: Too long+complex for a comment.

Comment: All the text and all three URLs fit with over 100 characters to spare.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla:Actually I am learning python two.Thanks for the advice.

Comment: -1 Pretty pathetic. Despite all the cloud, Python jobs are not exacty easy to find either. Delphi is way easier.

Comment: Did the asker say he's looking for a career? Don't push your opinions where they don't fit.

Comment: Sorry for trying to be helpful... :-(

Comment: Python is not a bona-fide OOP language: No true encapsulation. Worst possible language to start OOP with. The Python mantra is 'We're all adults here' - that means you did your 'growning up' somewhere else. Object Pascal is an EXCELLENT place to start. Pascal itself is language that was DESIGNED to teach good programming practices - thus C programmers find it restrictive.

Comment: @Mickey: Pascal was designed to learn good programming practices of the 1960s. The world has changed since them. Functional programming, decorating functions and writing readable code are very useful skills which you can't learn with Pascal. And OOP isn't encapsulation.

Comment: @Aaron: But Object Pascal is not your sixties language. If you don't know much about a language (and that you don't is obvious) why **comment** on it, and even post that as answer? FWIW, you can learn all these things and a lot more with Object Pascal. Encapsulation is one of the most important tenets of OO, BTW. And no, you are not being helpful, nor are you answering the question. This answer should be deleted.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I know 30 programming languages (know == I've written large programs in them). Pascal is one which I ditched pretty quickly because of the syntax. I'm aware that Pascal was designed to allow people to learn programming. In my oppinion, Wirth failed. There are only three people in the world who know how to *design* a programming language and he wasn't one of them. Van Rossum is one of them and I haven't found the other two, yet.

Comment: @Aaron, Object Pascal is not Wirth's old Pascal. It is far more advanced. And there are a few more good language designers, one of them being Anders Hejlsberg, who designed lots of the current Object Pascal before he moved to MS where he designed C#. Obviously you know lots of languages, but not Object Pascal. So I wonder what makes you think you can make comments on it.

Comment: And if Python was so well designed, I wonder why so many things had to be changed in version 3. I am not saying it is a bad language, but it shows that languages evolve, and Object Pascal has evolved a lot, in the last 25 years.